Finitely generated group in which maximal subgroups are commensurable
Is there a finitely generated torsion-free simple group such that every pair of maximal subgroups of the group are commensurable, i.e. for every pair of maximal subgroups $M$ and $N$ of the group, $|M:M\cap N|$ and $|N:M\cap N|$ are finite?

If one drops "torsion-free", quasi-finite groups do the job, but I'm not sure there is any other known example.

The combination of finitely generated, plus torsion-free, plus simple is kind of hard to come by; the only examples that I can think of are Burger-Mozes groups and various Hyde-Lodha groups. For Hyde-Lodha groups I would guess there are plenty of non-commensurable maximal subgroups (or maybe not, I suppose this could be a candidate...). For Burger-Mozes groups I really have no idea.
